# AWS EMR crashes because it cannot find modules from AWS Code Artifact when running PySpark

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I have an AWS EMR project with the following configuration:

- Three custom python projects in Code Artifact ( my_module_a, my_module_b, my_module_c)
- This post shows the libraries selected along with cluster configuration: [EMR cluster configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMbby.png)
- When I create the EMR cluster, I have a boot script to setup EMR machine with my code dependencies that downloads another module of mine ( my_module_d ) and a requirements.txt file from S3 and then, runs the installation process ( regular PyPI modules and my custom private modules from Code Artifact).
- I have a pypspark file to be submitted that calls a code from **my_module_d** and **my_module_d** uses the other three ones internally ( **my_module_a, my_module_b, my_module_c**). This pyspark code uses sparkcontext.parallelize [Parallelization](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.SparkContext.parallelize.html) and then, runs the code from **my_module_d**. The problem is that PySpark cannot recognize the existence of the other modules from CodeArtifact:

```
org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
22/01/28 21:44:43 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 1 in stage 8.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1224, in sum
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).fold(0, operator.add)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1078, in fold
    vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 949, in collect
    sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 8.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 8.0 (TID 80) (ip-10-1-124-58.ec2.internal executor 9): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_123123123/container_123123123/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 604, in main
    process()
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_123123123/container_123123123/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 594, in process
    out_iter = func(split_index, iterator)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2916, in pipeline_func
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2916, in pipeline_func
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 418, in func
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1224, in <lambda>
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_123123123/container_123123123/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 87, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in process_one_element
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_module_a'
```